# Best way to develop with Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, servlets

I'm trying to learn Tomcat but the problem for me is the that the Tomcat server has to be restarted each time I make changes to the code.

Is there any way to make Tomcat pick up changes to the code without having to restart the server?

Maybe an IDE (Like Eclipse or NetBeans) can be somehow used to develop for Tomcat and test all the changes right there in the IDE?

Comment: you can go with Hot code deployment in tomcat. details at : http://www.mkyong.com/eclipse/how-to-configure-hot-deploy-in-eclipse/

Comment: Just attach a debugger and "apply code changes". For JSP you can turn on change detection and simply update the files.

Answer (score 0):

Well if your putting your latest compiled files(classes/resources) under WEB-INF/Classes or lib folder you dont have to restart the server. You can can configure IDE's like Eclipse to configure this way where they can put latest compiled files under right target folder. Rcent Eclipse version comes up plugin where you can configure it to use existing tomcat server. You can also explore Mongrel Plugin which also serves the same purpose .

Answer (score -2):

Please have a look at "DCEVM". It's a Java runtime environment alternative that works just like a normal JRE but is able to reload class changes in almost all situations. Very cool, and it's free.

http://dcevm.github.io/

Installation is very straightforward, see explanation on the site.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what's wrong with this answer. Hot deploy in tomcat (as in any java web server) is limited by Java's inability to reload certain class changes. This is circumvented by DCEVM. It's basically a free JRebel alternative.